# Put an image header in \documentclass{letter}

Tags: graphics, header-footer, letters

Is there is any possibility to put an image header in a `letter` class document? I can put a footer image and an image for my signature, but I want to put an image on the top of the letter.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I took the liberty to rephrase your text a little bit. The way to was didn't sounded correct. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The letter class uses a page style called firstpage on the first page ...

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{headheight = 0.6in}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo.pdf}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo.pdf}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
    \begin{letter}{}%
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}%
```

It turns out the firstpage page style is only used if `\address` has not been used. If address has been used, then the first page style is empty and you need to add

```
\fancypagestyle{empty}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo.pdf}}}
```

Comment: Why is the logo in the first page missing when I add the command `\address{}`?

Comment: @hpesoj626 see the edit, `\address{}` causes the page style of the first page to be `empty`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extract from an in-house class we got for typesetting letters. Simply you just include the image.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@xl@logo
\@xl@logofalse
\def\setlogo#1{\@xl@logotrue\gdef\xl@companylogo{#1}}
 \setlogo{HSlogo}

\def\printlogo{%
 \if@xl@logo
  \includegraphics[width=.98\textwidth]{./\xl@companylogo}\par%
 \fi
}

\AtBeginDocument{\printlogo}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust your paper size with `geometry` to suit.

Comment: I don't think that this works with the letter class if you are using the letter environment for two reasons. The first is the letter environment will create a new page. The second is the first page in the letter class/letter environment is vertically centered.