# a line after text?

Tags: numbering, text-decorations, questionnaire

I am not aware of having a text with a colon and a line as a command. Is this possible?
I am using the `exam` document class so I can use the `\question` command for the proper numbering.

example:

```
 \documentclass{exam}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
     \question{Good} \oolonline
     \question{happy} \colonline
     \question{sad} \colonline
     \question{nervous} \colonline
     \question{angry} \colonline
 \end{questions}

 \end{document}
```

and it will appear like this:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the colons are supposed to be aligned, except when the word on the left is too long. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `\newcommand{\colonline}[1]{\question{#1\,:\rule{75pt}{0.4pt}}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `exam` class, you can have the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\colonline}[1]{\question{#1\,:\rule{75pt}{0.4pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
 \begin{questions}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
 \end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

You can use the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package to split the questions in two columns if there are more than 30 questions. If you want it in a command like format, you can use:

```
\newcommand{\synquestions}[2][2]{%
\begin{multicols}{#1}
\begin{questions}
#2
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
}
```

and implement it like this:

```
\synquestions{%
    \colonline{Good}
    \colonline{Happy}
    \colonline{Sad}
    \colonline{Nervous}
    }
```

Comment: If the number of question for example is 30 numbers no longer fil for one page, how would it be let to second column instead?

Comment: @kayla see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Something simpler if you are not after the alignment of the `\colonline`s

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcommand{\colonline}{: \makebox[0.75in]{\hrulefill}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
     \question{Good} \colonline
     \question{happy} \colonline
     \question{sad} \colonline
     \question{nervous} \colonline
     \question{angry} \colonline
 \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

As suggested by morbusg, it looks nicer to have the line align at the end.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{exam}

\newcommand{\colonline}{: \hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
     \question{Good} \colonline
     \question{happy} \colonline
     \question{sad} \colonline
     \question{nervous} \colonline
     \question{angry} \colonline
 \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

You can combine the answers here to come up with your own command. Generally, the definition of commands in LaTeX is given by:

`\newcommand{<command>}{<definition>}`

In our second definition of `\colonline`, `\colonline` is the command and what it does is to print `: \hrulefill`.

Sometimes, you can also see something like

`\newcommand{\bt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` where `1` is the number of optional arguments. (I usually do `\newcommand{\bt}[1]{\textbf{#1}\index{#1}}` so that all bold text are put in the index.)

It would be a good place to start reading [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort) to learn some of these useful tricks.

Comment: Maybe it would be nice to even go one step further and drop the makebox, leaving just the `\hrulefill` so it uses the whole horizontal space, thus aligning at end; used with two columns should work well overall.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\colonline}[1][2cm]{: \tikz[baseline={([yshift=0.3ex]current bounding box.center)}]{\draw (0,0) -- (#1,0);}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit : For the follow-up question you asked in comment, you can use an alternative `questions` environment defined with help of the `multicol` package.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\colonline}[1][2cm]{: \tikz[baseline={([yshift=0.3ex]current bounding box.center)}]{\draw (0,0) -- (#1,0);}} 

\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{manyquestions}{\begin{multicols}{2}\begin{questions}}{\end{questions}\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\begin{manyquestions}
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
  \question{Good} \colonline
  \question{happy} \colonline
  \question{sad} \colonline
  \question{nervous} \colonline
  \question{angry} \colonline
\end{manyquestions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Verron: how would I let this one lane proceed to a new column to prevent its continuation to the next page? example the question goes up to 30 plus number of question. for it to not proceed to the next page, how will I make this proceed to 2nd column?

Comment: @kayla : I editted to include a solution. However, such follow-up questions should be asked as a separate question, to maintain a clear Q/A interface for the site.