# How to make sure that a cover letter with two logos are perfectly aligned with the margins?

Tags: letters

I would like to make a cover letter with two logos. I based my attempt on @egreg's answer for a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129265/how-to-add-right-aligned-logo-to-top-of-standard-letter) but I want two logos instead of one. I thought I managed but I realized (using `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`) that the image to the left is not perfectly aligned with the margin.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
  textwidth=6.5in,
  textheight=8.5in,
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{mr. so and so \\ 123 main st \\ blah blah, IL 60617}

\makebox[\linewidth]{
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \large\bfseries Cowbell Place \\ 
  PO Box 5551212 \\ Chicago, IL 60617
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}%
}

\vspace{2cm}

\signature{some dude}

\opening{mr. so and so,}

\lipsum[1-2]

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

How do I make it perfectly aligned with the margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly protected your

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}%
% [... other stuff ...]
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}%
```

from spurious spaces by adding comment signs `%` at the end of the line, but you forgot one in the first `\makebox`

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{
% [ ... ]
}
```

The new line after the opening brace is treated as a space, and that's the empty space you see between the border and the image.

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{%  <--- THIS ONE IS IMPORTANT TOO
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \large\bfseries Cowbell Place \\ 
  PO Box 5551212 \\ Chicago, IL 60617
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: There you go -- I always forget something. Thank you for setting me straight, @campa. :)